# How to prove that $ \ln(1-e^{-x})=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{e^{-kx}}{k}$ if $x>0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How to prove that

$$
-\ln(1-e^{-x})=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{e^{-kx}}{k}$$ if $x>0$

Comment: Write down the Taylor series for $\ln(1 - x)$ centered at $0$.

Comment: Do you know the Taylor series for $\ln(1-t)$? You can easily look it up and substitute $e^{-x}=t$. Make sure you understand convergence.

Comment: Definitely want $k=1$, since you can't divide by zero...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*I use the $\color{red}{\text{red color}}$ to emphasize mistakes in your question*

We have for $|u|<1$ the geometric series
$$\frac1{1-u}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty u^k$$
so we integrate term by term with $|t|<1$
$$\color{red}-\ln(1-t)=\int_0^t\frac{du}{1-u}=\sum_{\color{red}{k=1}}^\infty \frac{t^k}{k}$$
so let $t=e^{-x}$ for $x>0$ we find
$$-\ln(1-e^{-x})=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{e^{-kx}}{k}$$